# Pandas - Check if a column label exists in another column's value and update the column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a long list of glossary word and would like to check if in a passage contains the glossary and mark 1 as yes, 0 as no, simplify as below:

```
>>> glossary = ['phrase 1', 'phrase 2', 'phrase 3']
>>> glossary
['phrase 1', 'phrase 2', 'phrase 3']

>>> df= pd.DataFrame(['This is a phrase 1 and phrase 2', 'phrase 1', 
'phrase 3', 'phrase 1 & phrase 2. phrase 3 as well'],columns=['text'])
>>> df
                                text
0        This is a phrase 1 and phrase 2
1                               phrase 1
2                               phrase 3
3  phrase 1 & phrase 2. phrase 3 as well
```

Concatenate it as below:

```
                                    text  phrase 1  phrase 2  phrase 3
0        This is a phrase 1 and phrase 2       NaN       NaN       NaN
1                               phrase 1       NaN       NaN       NaN
2                               phrase 3       NaN       NaN       NaN
3  phrase 1 & phrase 2. phrase 3 as well       NaN       NaN       NaN
```

I want to achieve for each of the glossary columns to compare with the text columns and update 1 if the glossary is in the text and 0 if not, in this case it would be

```
                                    text  phrase 1  phrase 2  phrase 3
0        This is a phrase 1 and phrase 2       1       1       0
1                               phrase 1       1       0       0
2                               phrase 3       0       0       1
3  phrase 1 & phrase 2. phrase 3 as well       1       1       1
```

Can you please advise how can i achieve it? Given that in my dataframe the glossary columns are around 3000 columns so I also want to generalise the logic such that it is based on the column label as a key to compare the corresponding text in each row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehension with [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html)  with cast to `int` for `0,1` DataFrame:

```
L = [df['text'].str.contains(x) for x in glossary]
df1 = pd.concat(L, axis=1, keys=glossary).astype(int)
print (df1)
   phrase 1  phrase 2  phrase 3
0         1         1         0
1         1         0         0
2         0         0         1
3         1         1         1
```

And then [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original:

```
df = df.join(df1)
print (df)
                                    text  phrase 1  phrase 2  phrase 3
0        This is a phrase 1 and phrase 2         1         1         0
1                               phrase 1         1         0         0
2                               phrase 3         0         0         1
3  phrase 1 & phrase 2. phrase 3 as well         1         1         1
```